# Why doesn't the CSS work on certain routes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I have no idea how to exactly explain this, but for some reason CSS doesn't work with certain routes with node.js & express.

For an example, CSS works perfectly fine for the route "/feed", but doesn't work at all with "/users/:username", even though the HTML file links to the same CSS file.

I've noticed that this isn't the first time this happened, and I have no idea why this is happening. If someone could explain to me / guide me to the right direction on what I should do, that would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a better example:

**Index route (CSS works for this route)**

```
// @ROUTE: Home Route
// @DESCRIPTION: Renders the homepage
server.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    filesDB.find({}).sort({createdAt: '-1'}).exec((err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            throw err
        } else {
            res.render('Home.ejs', {
                pageTitle: "Feed :: ImgHub",
                curSession: req.session,
                images: data
            })
        }
    })
})
```

**/users/:username route (CSS does not work for this route)**

```
// @ROUTE: User Route
// @DESCRIPTION: Renders all the posts that were uploaded by the selected user
server.get('/user/:username', (req, res)=> {
    const username = req.params.username

    filesDB.find({'uploader': username}).sort({createdAt: '-1'}).exec((err, data)=> {
        if(err) {
            throw err
        } else {
            res.render('User.ejs', {
                pageTitle: `${username} :: ImgHub`,
                curSession: req.session,
                images: data
            })
        }
    })
})
```

**Express static file**

```
server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/CSS'))
```

FYI: I get no errors in the console log on the website.

Comment: Would it help to follow this convention in app.use instead? `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'css')));` The second argument in that function has to be an object and I'm not sure that the + symbol and the css folder string works as such.

Comment: Can you show where & how you include your CSS files in the HTML? Given the `/user/:username` directory, your CSS file might be trying to be included from `/user/CSS/style.css` for example. Check your browser's console to see exactly what route your CSS file is trying to be included from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is in your HTML

You adding your CSS file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

And when your Url is something like `/feed` it would be ok, but on links like `/something/here` you would get your CSS searched as `/something/styles.css`. So you need to be specific and add `/` to your CSS declaration like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
```

So your styles will always be searched from the root that is `/`

Comment: I was about to write the same, an absolute route should work.